# mutt installaiton error on CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, mutt

I'm trying to install mutt on CentOS 6.7 and `./configure --prefix=$HOME/local` runs fine but at `make install` step, I run into this error below that I don't know how to solve. I tried with mutt 1.6.1 and 1.6.0 and this same error came up so it's probably some system setting that wasn't correct. How could I fix it?

```
gcc -std=gnu99  -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -g -O2   -o mutt addrbook.o alias.o attach.o base64.o browser.o buffy.o color.o crypt.o cryptglue.o commands.o complete.o compose.o copy.o curs_lib.o curs_main.o date.o edit.o enter.o flags.o init.o filter.o from.o getdomain.o group.o handler.o hash.o hdrline.o headers.o help.o hook.o keymap.o main.o mbox.o menu.o mh.o mx.o pager.o parse.o pattern.o postpone.o query.o recvattach.o recvcmd.o rfc822.o rfc1524.o rfc2047.o rfc2231.o rfc3676.o score.o send.o sendlib.o signal.o sort.o status.o system.o thread.o charset.o history.o lib.o muttlib.o editmsg.o mbyte.o mutt_idna.o url.o ascii.o crypt-mod.o safe_asprintf.o patchlist.o conststrings.o  pgp.o pgpinvoke.o pgpkey.o pgplib.o gnupgparse.o pgpmicalg.o pgppacket.o crypt-mod-pgp-classic.o smime.o crypt-mod-smime-classic.o resize.o   -lncursesw -lidn
/opt/gnu/bin/ld: curs_lib.o: undefined reference to symbol 'wtimeout'
/lib64/libtinfo.so.5: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [mutt] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I somehow fixed it.. not really understand why this fixed it.

After configure, in the Makefile, change the `LDFLAGS =` line to `LDFLAGS =  -lncurses -ltinfo`, then `make install` and it solved the issue.

Credit to this post: http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=129566.0, Tara-Rain-9.5ß's answer